# Save audio data from NSInputStream into a file

Tags: ios, avassetwriter, multipeer-connectivity, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream

I'm using **multipeerconnectivity framework** to transfer audio samples (`CMSampleBufferRef`) from the microphone. I can pass the samples using `NSOutputStream` for send data and `NSInputStream` for receive data.

Once I receive the data in the other device, I would like to use `AVAssetWriter` to save it into a file.

Is there any way to transform `NSData` to `CFSampleBufferRef`?

I need `CFSampleBufferRef` object because `AVAssetWriterInput` needs that object to append it to a file.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `CMSampleBufferCreate` I guess...

Comment: I can't find any example.... :(